# WSO2 API Manager 1.9 - Can not create new API

Tags: wso2

Good afternoon, I use the WSO AM 1.8 and am trying to use the new version ( 1.9 ) , but can not create new APIs. Simply lock on the first screen of creation and does nothing . They could help me ? I am using Debian and inline start WSO2 server.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Please attach here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any exceptions? I assume you are using https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Create+and+Publish+an+API

Comment: Yes, I am using this interface. The problem is, when I trying yo add resources, nothing happens and I can not continue. I already have APIs on 1.8.

Comment: In time. No errors are displayed on console or log.